# install sshuttle in a Google sdk docker image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-sdk

I am struggling to build this baby Dockerfile:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:286.0.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sshuttle
```

I am running on Ubuntu 18 with

```
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
```

My internet is up and running. I am not using docker-compose. Just plain

```
docker build -t test .
```

I get a bunch of DNS issues:

```
 ---> Running in fff5455a0cf0
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-buster InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'packages.cloud.google.com'
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/sid/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/cloud-sdk-buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'packages.cloud.google.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  iptables libip4tc2 libip6tc2 libjansson4 libnetfilter-conntrack3
  libnfnetlink0 libnftables1 libnftnl11 libxtables12 netbase nftables sudo
Suggested packages:
  firewalld kmod autossh
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  iptables libip4tc2 libip6tc2 libjansson4 libnetfilter-conntrack3
  libnfnetlink0 libnftables1 libnftnl11 nftables sshuttle sudo
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libxtables12 netbase
2 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 203 not upgraded.
Need to get 2491 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8740 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libjansson4 amd64 2.12-1
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 libnftnl11 amd64 1.1.5-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 libxtables12 amd64 1.8.4-3
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 libnftables1 amd64 0.9.3-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 nftables amd64 0.9.3-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 libip4tc2 amd64 1.8.4-3
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 libip6tc2 amd64 1.8.4-3
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 netbase all 6.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libnfnetlink0 amd64 1.0.1-3+b1
Err:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 libnetfilter-conntrack3 amd64 1.0.7-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 iptables amd64 1.8.4-3
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 sshuttle all 0.78.5-1
Err:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 sudo amd64 1.8.31p1-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libjansson4 amd64 2.12-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libnfnetlink0 amd64 1.0.1-3+b1
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 sshuttle all 0.78.5-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/j/jansson/libjansson4_2.12-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libn/libnftnl/libnftnl11_1.1.5-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/iptables/libxtables12_1.8.4-3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nftables/libnftables1_0.9.3-2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nftables/nftables_0.9.3-2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/iptables/libip4tc2_1.8.4-3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/iptables/libip6tc2_1.8.4-3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/netbase/netbase_6.1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libn/libnfnetlink/libnfnetlink0_1.0.1-3+b1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libn/libnetfilter-conntrack/libnetfilter-conntrack3_1.0.7-2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/iptables/iptables_1.8.4-3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sshuttle/sshuttle_0.78.5-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sudo/sudo_1.8.31p1-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y sshuttle # python3.6 python3-pip' returned a non-zero code: 100
/home/tschm/github/tensoralpha-strategy-research/Makefile:7: recipe for target '.make.build' failed
make: *** [.make.build] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Docker DNS could be breaking index file resolution. Try using `docker build --network=host`

Comment: why does my Docker say unknown flag: --host?